# How to get the Sort By option on Desktop in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-explorer, desktop

I don't have the Sort By option when I right-click on the Desktop in Windows Vista.

[image: option-na]

However, I do have this option if I right-click on an empty area in Windows Explorer while viewing Desktop folder (or any other folder).

[image: option-a]

Now that I think about it... I don't know if this has ever been there. Does Vista have this option? Anyone running Vista who can confirm or confute this? I do have Vista running but I also have [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) installed. That might have changed my configuration, so I can't be certain it was there previously.

I did see some screenshots on Google showcasing the Sort By option on the context menu. But it's hard to tell if this is Windows 7 or Windows Vista, as they are both very similar in terms of graphical interface.

I have a lot of files and folders on Desktop. I just want to sort them by type, right there on the Desktop, without having to open Windows Explorer and navigate to the actual Desktop folder. It would make my life a little easier.

This is Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit SP2.

Comment: Like you suspect, it's because of Fences.  Fences handles the sorting, it's what it's for after-all. :) Why not uninstall it and see if it reverts to normal?

Comment: I am not using Fences for all my icons on Desktop, only some of them. It's the icons that live outside of fences that I want to sort by type. Do you know any way of adding the Sort By option manually to Vista? Some registry mod maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Because the Fences handles the sorting of the icons etc. you have to uninstall it. That should solve the problem. Because it seems that Fences disable the sort on desktop.

Comment: I don't have access to the Vista machine at the moment. But I will try uninstalling Fences, see if it works, and report back.